# jQuery Draggables and Droppables Positioning

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-draggable

I'm using jquery UI and jQuery `draggable`, all my draggables use jquery *clone* helper and appends the *draggable* to *droppable*.

Here is my code

```
 $('#squeezePage #droppable').droppable({
  tolerance: 'fit',
  accept: '#squeezeWidgets .squeezeWidget',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
   var dropElem = ui.draggable.html();

   var clone = $(dropElem).clone();

   clone.css('position', 'absolute');
   clone.css('top', ui.absolutePosition.top);
   clone.css('left', ui.absolutePosition.left);

   $(this).append(clone);

   $(this).find('.top').remove();
   $(this).find('.widgetContent').slideDown('fast');

   $(this).find('.widgetContent').draggable({
    containment: '#squeezePage #droppable',
    cursor: 'crosshair',
    grid: [20, 20],
    scroll: true,
    snap: true,
    snapMode: 'outer',
    refreshPositions: true
   });

   $(this).find('.widgetContent').resizable({
    maxWidth: 560,
    minHeight: 60,
    minWidth: 180,
    grid: 20,
   });
  }
 });
```

I'm setting the position of the clone with `.css('top', ui.absolutePosition.top);` and `css('left', ui.absolutePosition.left);` but the position is relative to the BODY.

The position is not relative to the droppable which makes the draggable drop to random places. Overall, the droppable and draggable integration is not tight. I want to make it smoother.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm getting the offset of body and subtracting it from the offset of the widget clone.

```
clone.css('top', ui.position.top - droppableOffset.top);
clone.css('left', ui.position.left - droppableOffset.left);
```

It works!

Comment: where droppableOffset variable is jQuery('#squeezePage #droppable').offset();

Comment: I spent so many hours looking for a similar solution.. thank you so much.